# How to automatically switch to English when I switch to particular application?

Tags: input-source

I use 3 languages intensively on my iMac - English, Ukrainian and Russian. In some applications, however, I'd like the input to be automatically changed to a particular language.

For example, in software development applications, in console and in launchpad, I'd like to always get English turned on automatically.

Are there any ways to configure this?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings -> Keyboard and select the rightmost tab (Sorry only got German Os X at the moment, so I do not know the exact english words which will be displayed).

At the bottom there is a checkbox (the label is something with automatic change input source for documents ...) -> check it. Now you have to select the language for every document at first. But every time you switch back OS X will change the keyboard layout.